# With word boundaries (\b) in RegEx do I need to have it before AND after the word, or just before?

Tags: php, regex

If I want to match all occurrences of the word `foo` would I use `\bfoo\b` or without the last one? It seems both work, but what's proper?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would need to use both. Without the last `\b` you would get a match on strings such as:

```
"I love football"
"You foolishly left off your second word boundary"
```

Answer (score 4):

However, note that word boundary `\b`'s definition is based on the definition for `\w`: a word boundary is defined when it is between a non-word character and a word character, where word character is defined by `\w`. `\w` for ASCII string is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, so `\bfoo\b` also **rejects** cases such as:

```
foo123
3foo
foo_bar
fun_foo
```

Since digits and `_` are consider word character, if they are right next to `foo`, it won't form a word boundary, therefore `\bfoo\b` will not match any of the above.

Answer (score 2):

Given the following input:

```
foo foobar
```

This regular expression will match only the first `foo`:

```
\bfoo\b
```

This regular expression will match the first and also the `foo` in `foobar`:

```
\bfoo
```